# Gtk/GtkD Detect release of mouse button on window resize?

Tags: performance, graphics, gtk, d, gtkd

I'm trying to improve a plotting library that I wrote with GtkD (the D bindings for Gtk).  Scatter plots with a lot of points take a long time to resize.  I want to rescale the image, allowing pixelation, while the user is dragging the window edge to resize, and only re-render it when the mouse button is released.

Is there an API to detect whether the user is still holding down the mouse button to drag the window edge when a window is being resized?  If you are not familiar with GtkD, a response in terms of the C Gtk API would still be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting when a GTK window is done moving/resizing by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058392/detecting-when-a-gtk-window-is-done-moving-resizing-by-the-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a 500 millisecond timeout to the redraw (resetting the timer on each resize event) this allows a user to see a preview while dragging